# Angular updating matTableDatasource with interval brings scroll to the top of page

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have a mat-table which needs to be updated about the changes. I set an interval and inside the interval I call a method which is like

```
updateMatTable(offset: number, size: number): void {

        offset = offset * size;

        /* GET DATA FROM REST SERVICE */

            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.newTableData.dataRows);

        });

    }
```

it seems like equating dataSource to the newTableData brings the scroll position to top of the page **only when we are at a scroll position where we can see under the mat-table (near bottom of page ) and that the table needs scrolling down**

Is this a bug about the library or am I missing something about mat-tables.

Thank you for the answers

Comment: do you need to replace all the data listed in table? or just to append new data to the existing one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,I added a change detector under the codes and it is not behaving strange somehow. I would like to have an explanation tho.

```
    updateMatTable(offset: number, size: number): void {
    
            offset = offset * size;
    
            /* GET DATA FROM REST SERVICE */
    
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.newTableData.dataRows);

                this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    
            });
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case scrolling page to the top was caused by **stickyEnd** directive added to one of the column of mat-table.

Answer (score 0):

I've now encountered this bug/quirk of mat-table with sticky columns on a scrolling page. Another workaround (besides removing sticky columns) is to set a static height on the mat-table element such as `height: 600px;` I've tried setting height to a `%` or `vh` but the bug persists.